# Does GCH imply the power set of every well ordered set is well ordering

Tags: set-theory

In ZF with GCH, can we prove that the power set of every well ordered set can be well ordered?

Comment: GCH gives you choice.

Comment: Ah, Ok, thanks. But then that clinches it.

Comment: Are there good materials show that GCH implies AC?

Comment: @isabhud See Jech, The Axiom of Choice, Theorem 9.1 p.133

Comment: Please give your questions descriptive titles. "About well ordering of power sets" is not a very useful title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the absence of choice, it's not immediately clear what GCH should say. One possible formulation would be that $2^{\aleph_\alpha}=\aleph_{\alpha+1}$ for all $\alpha.$ This manifestly implies that the power set of every well-ordered set is well-orderable. Another possible statement is that if $x\preceq y\preceq P(x)$ then either $x\simeq y$ or $y\simeq P(x),$ which does imply the same, although not obviously.

It turns out these are actually equivalent because they both imply choice, and they are clearly equivalent under choice.

For proof the first implies choice, see Theorem 9 of [Andrés's notes](https://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2009/11/11/502-equivalents-of-the-axiom-of-choice/#more-2422) or theorem 9.1 Jech's Axiom of choice book. For the second (probably more pertinent since you initially asked if it implies the power set of an ordinal is well-ordered), it's covered in Chapter IV section 12 of Cohen's monagraph, or chapter 9 of Smullyan and Fitting's book.